# Auto Layout implementation in iOS using VFL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am using the auto layout using the visual formatting language.

In horizontal mode, I can include both labels in a single line of code like this

```
 constraints  = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[Btn1]-10-[dummyLabel1]-10-[Lbl2]-10-[dummyLabel2]-10-[Btn2]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

I had to use to two lines of constraints like this to place two objects in vertical mode.

```
 constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[dummyLabel]-16-[fixedLabel]-13-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[dummyLabel2]-16-[fixedLabel]-13-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Is there any way i can do this in a single line for the vertical mode as well using VFL?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish by doing this in code, but if you need to tweak a constraint created in interface builder after the view is initialized, you can drag an outlet from the _constraint_ onto your ViewController and alter it programmatically later.

Comment: Currently there is no XIB file implemented for this class. And i am trying to check if it can be done in VFL itself. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's a lot of different ways to do Auto Layout: in Interface Builder, using the VFL, creating NSLayoutConstraints programmatically, or using Layout Anchors. Each has their own shortcomings. This is one of the places the VFL breaks down.